# Spring Data Repository Save - How to know it data is really saved?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When saving data into a database I really want to know that is saved. But my spring application does not seem to throw an error/exception.

So what I've done is to have a break point in my application right before the save operation `myRepository.save(entity)`. When it stops on the break point I stop my DB service and then continue to save.

I get no exception, my saved entity returned by `save()` looks fine. But nothing is saved in the DB. I can even do `myRepository.findOne(id)` and it will find the entity. How do I know that it's really saved?

If the DB goes down before my my `@Transactional` method then I get errors but not when it stops in the middle of the method.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't in the database? Normally, when using `@Transactional`, it will flush changes to the database at least at the end of that method (when the transaction commit happens). If the database is down at that time, it should throw an exception. If you use `repository.findOne(id)` it should have triggered a flush as well if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Wrapping it in a service call worked wonders for me. Then I  got all the exceptions I needed. So you're probably correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to wrap my db calls `myRepository.save(entity)` in a service class or a separate method annotated with `@Transactional`.

This way when the method gets called, that has `@Transactional`, I will get an exception thrown. Since the commit is done after the method is called. Thank you [Maria Sekar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4532512/maria-sekar) for the insights. Before I had the `@Transactional` annotation on the Controller, which gave me an error but I had no chance to do anything with it.

So the solution, simplified

**In Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/notification", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Notification saveNotification(@RequestBody Notification notification) {
    Notification savedNotification = null;
    try {
        myService.save(notification);
    } catch (SQLServerException e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveNotification(e);
    }
    return savedNotification;
}
```

**In Service class**

```
@Transactional
public save(Notification notification) {
    myRepo.save(notification);
}
```

Comment: Dont put @Transactional in your save method. It should begin when there is a http request within your filters or interceptors only, because you have to do some business logic as well right if it fails then you have to revert those stuffs that are done within that request right (Except like last ping time / login time....) Thats the best practice.

Comment: Ok, I should clarify. All my business logic will also be in this service "save" method, I guess I should name it something else, ok?

Comment: It is not useful to use @ Transactional in this scenario. The main purpose of @ Transactional is that if you are doing more then 1 operation on database and you want that either all or none should be executed in case of error so the state of all DB's remain same.  It is the scenario where you use @ Transactional in your case .save method simple returns you the object you have passed it and in case of success it should be same object to otherwise it want be same object. so you can check this and decide either save operation has been performed or not.

Answer (score 2):

`repository.save()` will not necessarily flush changes to the database. It will only do so when:

- The end of the transaction is reached (= the end of the `@Transactional` method)
- A depending call is made (eg. when you start using `repository.findAll()` or `repository.findOne(id)`)
- ...

This is mentioned in the [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#d5e720) as well as **transactional write-behind**:

> To reduce lock contention in the database, the physical database transaction needs to be as short as possible. Long database transactions prevent your application from scaling to a highly-concurrent load. Do not hold a database transaction open during end-user-level work, but open it after the end-user-level work is finished. This is concept is referred to as transactional write-behind.

This means that if your database is down at the moment changes are being flushed, you should actually get an exception. However, this could happen at the end of the method, somewhere else, ... .

This is also the reason why it's sometimes difficult to track back why an exception happened, because the flush could be triggered much later than when the actual save happens in the code.

You can manually flush to the database when necessary, if you're using the `repository.flush()` or `repository.saveAndFlush()` methods, but normally you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

All those operations will be done in the memory until the commit is called. After commit only it will be persisted into respective dbs. After commit only db related triggers like foriegn key / related stuffs will be called by db and if error then throws else your repository will simple return the entity object.

Comment: Ahh...of course. I did not think about that, maybe putting that db calls in a service class enable me to catch these exceptions?